# Magento 2 : how to add content on customer dashboard

Tags: magento2.3, template

On customer dashboard you see this

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ddf42caaf25311f10b23b95a92746f99943e045e/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml#L23

`<?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.account.dashboard.info.extra'); ?>`

Can you embed content into the template using this marker in an module?

Just add content to the marker. Not override the entire info.phtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution

app/code/Xigen/UsernameLogin/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="Magento_Customer::account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <container name="customer.account.dashboard.info.extra">
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer.account.dashboard.info.extra.username.login" template="Xigen_UsernameLogin::account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
                </container>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then only need to provide

app/code/Xigen/UsernameLogin/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml

```php
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info $block */
?>
<p>
    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Username: %1', $block->getUsername())) ?><br>
</p>
```

That's the cleanest solution I could get working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dominic for sharing, This also will work without the need to redefine the core block again

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_info">
            <container name="customer.account.dashboard.info.extra">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer.account.dashboard.info.extra.username.login"
                       template="Xigen_UsernameLogin::account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```